# How to know when and what an user submits a form in a pop-up from different site?

Tags: php

I have seen this on some social exchange sites, where you simply click the Tweet/Like/Follow/Subscribe/etc button and the page detects us clicking it without a log-in. I am not sure how exactly they do it, but I would like to do the same thing. Survey sites do the same, but I am not sure if they have a code inside the survey itself.

Note that my site has not access to the site with the form (let's call it site2) and site2 has no API. Social exchange sites use the social network's domain, but it is fine using my own domain if that makes anything simpler.

It would be fine detecting if the submit button gets clicked, but knowing what the user sumbits would be a bonus.

Comment: You mean like when a blog post on the internet has a FB like button and you click on this button, FB will know that you clicked on this button?

Comment: @Dees040 No, I mean something like you get paid to comment a blog post on site2 but I want to detect if the user has made a comment in it and what he wrote.

Answer (score 0):

Well you do need API for to do such a thing. Like the Like/Follow etc works is basically your user doing request via your site to the social site API (there will be log-in, if the user is not logged in, or stored cookie etc)

After the request, there will be a response from that API, that your own site can read and display or do something else.

If the site2 has the form, you could see the code on how and what data will be sent to where, with witch method.. But the site2 may reject your request

Comment: I never heard about witch method, did you mean switch?

Let's say the pop-up I create has a RESTful link (site2.com/?name=test) and I would like to know if he really submits "test" as name or if he changes it. Is that possible without an API? @Maanus

Comment: What i meant was will it be GET, POST, PUT etc method, by witch method it will be ;) (mostly it will be POST for forms, sometimes even GET)

You can allways see all the values submited in your php code
`print_r($_POST);` and `print_r($_GET);`

You can check the value from url by `isset($_GET['name'])`

Comment: Let's see, it is a POST method. How can I use that code to print a value from a site where I can't access the code?

Comment: You cant access a php code, the only thing you could do is see the input values in html, that will be sent

Comment: Mind telling me how?

Comment: [Alot of important text here](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_forms.asp)

Basically when an input `<input type='text' name='mytextfield' />` will be submited, depending on the mehod (lets say POST) the server will read it by the name `$_POST['mytextfield']`.. by reading your comment in your post, i realize bit more what youre trying to acomplish.. The answer will be: I think its not possible, you cannot detect the user comment in site2, unless the site2 provides you that info, unless you get a callback from that site2 after the user submits comment